# Execution Timeout Expired errors using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, asynchronous

My code below starts out great and seems to run pretty quickly but then I will start getting this error message after awhile. I realize that Entity Framework/Dbcontext is not thread safe and this is probably causing the issue so is there a way to change this code so that it keeps the same performance and doesn't have issues with not closing threads which is probably causing the problem or is there another way to speed up this process? I have over 9000 symbols to download and insert into a database and I tried doing basic for loops with the await command but it was extremely slow and took more than 10 times longer to achieve the same results.

```
public static async Task startInitialMarketSymbolsDownload(string market)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> symbolList = new List<string>();
        symbolList = getStockSymbols(market);

        var historicalGroups = symbolList.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                  .GroupBy(x => x.i / 50)
                  .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.x).ToArray());

        await Task.WhenAll(historicalGroups.Select(g => Task.Run(() => getLocalHistoricalStockData(g, market))));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

public static async Task getLocalHistoricalStockData(string[] symbols, string market)
{
    // download data for list of symbols and then upload to db tables
    string symbolInfo = null;

    try
    {
        using (financeEntities context = new financeEntities())
        {
            foreach (string symbol in symbols)
            {
                symbolInfo = symbol;
                List<HistoryPrice> hList = Get(symbol, new DateTime(1900, 1, 1), DateTime.UtcNow);
                var backDates = context.DailyAmexDatas.Where(c => c.Symbol == symbol).Select(d => d.Date).ToList();
                List<HistoryPrice> newHList = hList.Where(c => backDates.Contains(c.Date) == false).ToList<HistoryPrice>();

                foreach (HistoryPrice h in newHList)
                {
                    DailyAmexData amexData = new DailyAmexData();
                    // set the data then add it
                    amexData.Symbol = symbol;
                    amexData.Open = h.Open;
                    amexData.High = h.High;
                    amexData.Low = h.Low;
                    amexData.Close = h.Close;
                    amexData.Volume = h.Volume;
                    amexData.AdjustedClose = h.AdjClose;
                    amexData.Date = h.Date;
                    context.DailyAmexDatas.Add(amexData);
                }

                // now save everything
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(symbol + " added to the " + market + " database!");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's not thread safe, but not only are you not doing any threading here, you're also not passing the context around.

Comment: @DavidG I thought I was using threading because I have the Task.Run command run for each group of 50 symbols in the first method. Is there a better way to write this code that solves my constant Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding errors?

Comment: maybe you could try handling the connection yourself in this scenario. Also, I'm not quite sure why you are trying to do it asynchronously if each task would need a write lock on the table for the entirety of its execution time anyways.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Is there a way to edit the code to run the downloading info step for all symbols and then do batch inserts all at once into the datatable using ef at the very end?

Comment: sure there is, just grab all the iqueryables and execute all of them in one transaction.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I don't think that would work because we are talking about millions of rows

Comment: @DarthVegan How did you solde this problem ? I have the same problem in my code. I want to loop throught millions of rows.

Comment: @THEHOLYSPIRIT I did two things that fixed the issue for me. First I swapped the using statement and put it inside the foreach loop instead. Second and most important I used amazing software called z entity framework (https://entityframework-extensions.net/) instead of the built in entity framework and my program sped up a thousand times or so faster

Comment: @DarthVegan So did you used **await context.BulkSaveChangesAsync();** istead of **await context.SaveChangesAsync();** in your code ?

Comment: @THEHOLYSPIRIT yes I use await context.BulkSaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); and I also moved it right outside of the for loop so I only run it once instead of each time. That also saved a bunch of time